# R infer and group_by - generate only one summary statistic for bootstrapping without any levels

Tags: r, bootstrap-4, confidence-interval

Is there a reason why my group_by doesn't seem to be working with the infer package? I'm trying to generate confidence intervals using bootstrapping.

This code works fine:

```
library(infer)

mtcars %>%
  specify(response = wt) %>%
  generate(reps = 1000, type = 'bootstrap') %>%
  calculate(stat = 'mean') %>%
  get_ci(level = 0.95)
  

lower_ci
<dbl>
upper_ci
<dbl>
2.897742    3.535187
```

But when I group mtcars together into a long data frame and then try infer using group_by, I get only one set of summary rows (nothing is grouped).

```
remove(mtcars)

mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(am = as_factor(am), cyl = as_factor(cyl), gear = as_factor(gear), vs = as_factor(vs),  carb = as_factor(carb))

mtcars_long_numeric <- mtcars %>%
  select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = 'names', values_to = 'values')

mtcars_long_numeric %>%
  group_by(names) %>%
  specify(response = values) %>%
  generate(reps = 1000, type = 'bootstrap') %>%
  calculate(stat = 'mean') %>%
  get_ci(level = 0.95)


lower_ci
<dbl>
upper_ci
<dbl>
56.24676    84.73951
```

As a final small test, I filter my new data frame by names == wt and get the same value as in my first run. So it doesn't look like anything is obviously wrong except that group_by is not working?

```
mtcars_long_numeric_filtered <- mtcars_long_numeric %>%
  filter(names == "wt")

mtcars_long_numeric_filtered %>%
  specify(response = values) %>%
  generate(reps = 1000, type = 'bootstrap') %>%
  calculate(stat = 'mean') %>%
  get_ci(level = 0.95)

lower_ci
<dbl>
upper_ci
<dbl>
2.91292 3.542712
```

I'm surprised this is giving me trouble - I thought infer was designed using these dplyr-type verbs/syntax and the example I have here I think is probably generally useful in other contexts, although maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the functions from `infer` package don't recognise the grouping attributes of tibbles. You may split the dataset into list of smaller datasets, apply the function and combine the results.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(infer)

mtcars_long_numeric %>%
  split(.$names) %>%
  map_df(~.x %>% 
  specify(response = values) %>%
  generate(reps = 1000, type = 'bootstrap') %>%
  calculate(stat = 'mean') %>%
  get_ci(level = 0.95), .id = 'name')

#  name  lower_ci upper_ci
#  <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 disp    190.     274.  
#2 drat      3.42     3.79
#3 hp      123.     172.  
#4 mpg      18.0     22.3 
#5 qsec     17.2     18.5 
#6 wt        2.88     3.57
```